# spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property

Tags: angular

I got following error when running `ng test` or
`ng test --include src/folder/component-name.component.spec.ts`

Error Message

- Error: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js):
  Error: component-file.component.spec.ts is missing from the TypeScript compilation. Please make sure it is in your tsconfig via the 'files' or 'include' property.
  at /node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/loader.js:60:26
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
  at runNextTicks (node:internal/process/task_queues:65:3)
  at processImmediate (node:internal/timers:437:9)

tsconfig.spec.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/spec",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "types": [
      "jasmine",
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "files": [
    "test.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "include": [
    "**/*.spec.ts",
    "**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.app.json

```
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "module": "esnext",
    "types": [
      "node"
    ]
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ],
  "files": [
    "main.ts",
    "polyfills.ts"
  ]
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "importHelpers": true,
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "es7",
      "dom"
    ],
    "module": "esnext",
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*",
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
  ]
}
```

I guess this error, the test-component used lazy-module..,

Comment: You'll also want to close your `include` array with a `]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're excluding any `spec.ts` files from compilation. Remove this line from the `exclude` arrays.

```json
"**/*.spec.ts"
```

Comment: This worked for me, I have added those files' names in the exclude section previously and after removing those entries it's working fine!!